# Email doesn't send to user

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a contact form, where the user types their personal information and the message that wants to send to me (admin), what would happen is that i would receive an email with their information and message sent, and at the same time the user would receive an email saying that their information was sent sucessfully. At this moment all of this works, but the problem is, the message only sends to the user when i force it, which means oh the function "addAddress" I type the email address that i want that to go to, but i would like to send to everyone who fills that form, which is not working, it only sends to me (admin)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Mensagem (NomeM, EmailMen, Assunto, Mensagem) VALUES ('$NomeM', '$EmailMen','$Assunto', '$Mensagem')";
$res = $lig->query($sql);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Porto = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $mail->Username='admin@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password='***';

    $mail->setFrom($_POST['EmailReser']);
    $mail->addAddress('admin@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['EmailReser']);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject='New message from your website';
    $mail->Body = "message from user";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $result="Something went wrong. Try again";
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?cmd=home');

        //========  User  ========
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Porto = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
        $mail->Username='admin@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password='***';

        $mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['EmailReser']);  // If i added 'user@gmail.com' it would work
        $mail->addReplyTo('admin@gmail.com');

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject='Your message was received';
        $mail->Body = "message from admin";

        if(!$mail->send()){
            $result="Something went wrong. Try again";
        } else{
            header('Location: index.php?cmd=home');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if a static value works, but `$_POST['EmailReser']` in the same place doesn’t - then the first guess would be, that this variable simply doesn’t contain what you _think_ it does. So make a debug output (use `var_dump`) to _verify_ that.

Comment: Imran has provided an answer that will resolve you issue. However, it may be useful to specify the following options for a request `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only`

Comment: i did and nothing changed, the email to the admin was  sent the same way and the user continued not to receive the email

Comment: should I insert that code on the admin side or the user side? @atoms

Comment: There is no “admin side” and “user side” here. You have one user, submitting one form - and you want to send two emails based on that. So, _send two emails_ in the script where you process this form data.

Comment: @someone place it after the portTo line. Ensure that its set to 0 or 2 when going live. Will help debug any SMTP issues

Comment: i did and again. nothing changed

Comment: $mail->Porto = 587; remove the "o"

Answer (score 1):

in code at :

```php
...
} else {
    header('Location: index.php?cmd=home');
...
```

You have redirected user to another page after sending first mail.
After redirection `$_POST` data is lost, so second email will not be triggered.

Comment: Oh, so i should direct both users to the same page? i.e contact form?

Comment: @Someone _“so i should direct both users to the same page”_ - that doesn’t even make sense, your admin is hardly going to sit in front of the site opened in their browser at the same time, when any arbitrary user fills out the contact form. Send both mails from within the _one_ script that the form data gets send to, when the user submits it. The admin is not involved in any active capacity here at all.

Comment: @Someone If you have to redirect then redirect with data or redirect user after sending both the mails.

Comment: i got lost of what you just said, i'm new at this @04FS

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property as `Porto`; it's just `Port`, so it will be using the default port 25.

Don't do this:

```
$mail->setFrom($_POST['EmailReser']);
```

that's forgery and gmail will not let you do it. Put your own address in the from address (as you do for the admin email) and put the submitter into a reply-to (as you're doing already).

It's wasteful creating two PHPMailer instances - create one and send both messages with it. This will also allow you to use keepalive, which will make the send faster.

You are using an old version of PHPMailer, so I've updated your script to use the current version, using composer to load it - if you're not using it yet, now would be a good time to learn.

It will also not send if the submitter's email address property is not a valid address, something which you were not catching before.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //Enable exceptions
try {
    //Set all common properties
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = 'admin@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '***';
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    //Set up recipients
    $mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('admin@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['EmailReser']);

    $mail->Subject = 'New message from your website';
    $mail->Body = "message from user";

    //If this fails, it will be caught below, so no need for an `if`
    $mail->send();

    //Re-use existing instance
    //Reset recipients, don't need to touch reply-to or from address
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['EmailReser']);

    $mail->Subject = 'Your message was received';
    $mail->Body = "message from admin";
    $mail->send();
    header('Location: index.php?cmd=home');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong. Try again ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Is there a need to upload a new file? if so,  could you send me a link so i could download it?

Comment: The latest version is always [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Read the readme for instructions on how to load the classes without composer.

Comment: well, i already did it and it didn't work, i guess it's because i don't have the autload file, it wasn't on the link you gave me

Comment: Thats because it's created by composer, so if you're not using composer it won't be there, so do what the readme says and load the classes individually. You will need the PHPMailer, Exception, and SMTP classes.

Comment: i made `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php'; ` and i get a white page

Comment: A white page generally means a fatal error, so either enable error display in your script (`ini_set('display_errors', true);`) temporarily, or look in your web server's error log.

Comment: it's still the same way, and i don't have access to my error log (i guess only someone superior at my school does)

Comment: but i found the mistake on my post earlier, i was using the wrong variable "EmailReser" should be "EmailMen" which is the one i defined

Comment: If you use that ini_set call, you should be able to override the config.